# vba conditional formating on a range of 2 different columns

Tags: excel, vba

How do I set the conditional formatting on 2 different columns of data if column(L) <> Column(H) using VBA.  The format I would like consist of Font:Red, BackFill: Yellow, for the entire row.

This is what I have so far.

```
    With Range("H:H,L:L")
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$H1<>$L1"
       With Range("H:H,L:L").FormatConditions(1).Font
            .Color = -16776961
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End With
```

Comment: And what is this doing that is in error?

Answer (score 0):

No error and  Thanks for your time, however, I found the solution elsewhere.

```
         With Rows("1:1048576")
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ROW()<>1,$H1<>$L1)"
        With Rows("1:1048576").FormatConditions(1).Font
            .Bold = True
            .Color = -16776961
        End With

        With Rows("1:1048576").FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
        End With
    End With
```